# Ajax Query making the duplicate request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  $('#dialog .join').click(function () {
            email = $.trim($(this).parent().find('.email').val());
            if (email != "Email Address" && email.length > 5) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/newsletter/join',
                    data:{ 'email':email, 'pid':$('#dialog .pid').html().trim() }
                });

                $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
                if(link){
                $('.job .outbound').off('click');
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

This is the code that is fired an ajax request , in debug mode I see the first request to servlet is made immediately after the

```
  $('#dialog .join').click(function () {
```

And then it goes through all steps ending up making a second request ,

I am still confused to understand why the first request is made as soon as it enters the body ,

There could be a chance i can control using flag , but i am using this utility for other form and that is working fine

Following is the complete function i am using

```
function showDialog(link) {
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal:true,
    height:'auto',
    width:'auto',
    resizable:false,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    dialogClass:'newsletter',
    open:function (event, ui) {


        $('#dialog .email').css("color", "#A9A9A9").val('Email Address').blur().one("focus", function () {
            $(this).val("").css("color", "black");
        });


        $('#dialog .join').click(function () {
            email = $.trim($(this).parent().find('.email').val());
            if (email != "Email Address" && email.length > 5) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/newsletter/join',
                    data:{ 'email':email, 'pid':$('#dialog .pid').html().trim() }
                });

                $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
                if(link){
                $('.job .outbound').off('click');
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Perhaps the entire event is firing twice  - How is the `showDialog` function triggered

Comment: Does not look like the event is firing up twice , i went through the debug mode couple of times

Comment: Did you try removing 'return true' in your code after successful ajax post?

Comment: It is  same it looks problem is not with return ,  first call to servlet is made after the .click() function

Comment: Thanks All , Ryan was right in first place .  I included one java script file which caused the duplication of code , that is why the code was getting executed twice